# How to add pre-order functionality for products in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, preorder

I am trying to add pre-order functionality for simple and variable products. I got  some plugins but I would like to add it with the help of own functions. How can i achieve it?

Comment: Use the plugin, why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: Adding the plugins didnt worked for variable product as I have changed the attribute display to radio instead of dropdown.

Comment: I am using YITH Pre-Order for WooCommerce plugin for pre order functionality. 
Actually I have a custom filter that i have developed myself with woocommerce product queries. Now I need to add pre-order in the filter and if a user selects pre-order than the products that are selected on pre-order will be displayed. How can i achieve it?

Comment: $wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
                    'post_type' => 'product',
                    'posts_per_page' => $limit,
                    'meta_key' => '_ywpo_preorder',
                    'meta_value' => 'yes',
                    'meta_compare' => '==',
                    'paged' => $paged
                ));

This thing works for simple product only , I need it modify for displaying all variable products that are marked for pre-order.